# create custom class that extend thread in yii2

Tags: php, multithreading, class, yii2

how create custom class not extend components class ?

class :

```
 namespace common\components;

 class AsyncOperation extends Thread {

  public function __construct($arg) {
    $this->arg = $arg;
}

public function run() {
    if ($this->arg) {
        $sleep = mt_rand(1, 10);
        printf('%s: %s  -start -sleeps %d' . "<br />", date("g:i:sa"),     $this->arg, $sleep);
        sleep($sleep);
        printf('%s: %s  -finish' . "<br />", date("g:i:sa"), $this->arg);
      }
   }

}
```

yii2 controller:

```
   public function actionTest() {
  // Create a array
    $stack = array();

//Iniciate Miltiple Thread
    foreach (range("A", "D") as $i) {
        $stack[] = new AsyncOperation($i);
    }

    // Start The Threads
    foreach ($stack as $t) {
        $t->start();
    }
}
```

error:

```
 PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'common\components\Thread' not found
```

> This class is working perfect in pure php app
>   And Pthread is installed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extends `Something` means that class `Something` searched in current namespace. `\Something` means that class searched in root namespace. See [basics of namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).

You don't have class `common\components\Thread` in your `common\components` namespace. In your case use `class AsyncOperation extends \Thread {`

Answer (score 1):

Someone already gave you the answer you were looking for ... however ...

I notice you have markup in your thread, and are using a web framework.

I'm going to assume you are creating threads at the frontend of your web application, inside a web server: [This is a terrible idea](http://blog.krakjoe.ninja/2014/10/but-is-it-web-scale.html).

The latest releases of pthreads [prohibit execution inside a web server](http://blog.krakjoe.ninja/2015/09/the-worth-of-advice.html), you are going to need to do things differently if you want to use PHP7 and pthreads, which is soon to be the only supported way to use pthreads.

Comment: no it's just test but i'm use it in backend of restful api in yii2!!

Comment: I'm glad you're using it properly ;)